# How can an Apallie infiltrate a humanoid society if it only speaks sylvan?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, languages

The [appallie](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/apallie/) ooze can assume humanoid form and try to fulfill its desire to become one.

But how does it interact with humanoids if it only speaks sylvan?

The only core race that has sylvan as a bonus language are elves.

Answer (score 2):

There's no in-game reason given in its description for it to specifically know Sylvan, or really any language at all. I can only assume that it learned its language from its creator. If I wanted to use this creature as a GM, I think a reasonable modification is to switch Sylvan with whatever language is the primary language of the being who created it.